Obtain force constants from normal modes
I am trying to reproduce an QTAIM analysis by Foroutan-Nejad et al. (https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/chem.201402177). Instead of only looking into the equilibrium structure of organometallic complexes, they also take a look at non-equilibrium structures. They write for their procedure:

To generate non-equilibrium geometries for our topological analysis, we surveyed the vibrational spectrum of each molecule seeking for large-amplitude and low-frequency normal modes with small force constants (f<0.7 mDyn Å−1). Then, a set of “testing” non-equilibrium geometries were generated along each normal mode. Only those members of the testing set were used for topological analysis whose energy difference to the total energy of the equilibrium geometry was at most equal to the energy of the first excited vibrational state of the corresponding normal mode, which is populated significantly at room temperature.

I am using ORCA and have run an optimisation and a frequency calculation, however, I am struggling to find a way to calculate the respective force constants. I stumbled upon a similar, but still unanswered question here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/how-to-extract-force-constants-for-normal-modes-from-orca
Following the idea there:
$$\tilde{\nu}=\sqrt{k_i^{\prime\prime}}/(2\pi \times 137 \times 5.29\times 10^{-9})$$
would result in
$$k_i^{\prime\prime} = (\tilde{\nu} \times 2\pi \times 137 \times 5.29\times 10^{-9})^2$$
Applying this to the example in the paper (Figure 2(a)) where $\tilde{\nu} = \pu{387 cm-1}$ is given together with a force constant of $f = \pu{0.52 mDyn \mathring{A}-1}$ results in
$$k_i^{\prime\prime} = 3.1055 \times 10^{-6}.$$
Where the units of $k_i^{\prime\prime}$ are $\frac{\text{energy}}{(\text{mass} \times \text{length}^2)} = \frac{1}{\text{time}^2}$. However, the units for $f$ in the paper are given as $\pu{mDyn//\mathring{A}} = \frac{\pu{10E-8 N}}{\pu{10E-10 m}} = \pu{10^2 kg//s2}$. Thus, some key part in the conversion of a wavenumber to the corresponding force constant is missing, which I can not figure out. Is there a straight forward mathematical way for this conversion or an option to have force constants given out directly by ORCA?

I cannot answer this question, but this post from the Orca forum might help you work out the force constants: https://orcaforum.kofo.mpg.de/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=10939&p=45355&hilit=force+constant#p45379 And perhaps the rogue kg comes from mass weighting of the hessian/normal mode?

@isolatedmatrix While the mentioned programs did not yield the force constants, the reference to the description of how Gaussian is computing the force constants is probably going to solve my problems. I will need some time to check the steps and convert them to code to test this out. I'll report back.

Please do—I would like to know how to calculate the force constants from an Orca hessian as well!
